# Redirect a user to the page they were trying to access after login in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a page that is restricted to logged in users (say it's called '/authed-page'). When a non-authenticated user visits this page they are prompted to click a button to login and they are then taken to the login url: '/login'

Now after they login I want them to get redirected to the page they had been trying to visit, '/authed-url', but I can't figure out how to do this!

Things I've tried:

1) Declaring a function redirect_to_authed_url in my functions.php file like this

```
function redirect_to_authed_url( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    return "/post-a-job";
}
```

Then in the template for authed-url.php when I detect the user isn't logged in I do this:

```
<?php add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirect_to_authed_url', 10, 3 ); ?>
```

However this doesn't work I think because the user presses a button which generates another http request which sends them to the '/login' url which means the redirect filter is lost.

2) Setting a cookie when someone visits '/authed-url' and they are not logged in called 'redirect_url'. Then I declare this in my theme's functions.php file

```
function redirect_request( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['login_redirect']) && strpos($_COOKIE['login_redirect'], 'http') === false) {
        $redirect_url = $_COOKIE['login_redirect'];
        unset $_COOKIE['login_redirect'];
        return $redirect_url;
    } else {
        return('/');
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work because I can't figure out where to set the cookie. I keep getting the warning:

```
WARNING: CANNOT MODIFY HEADER INFORMATION - HEADERS ALREADY SENT
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. This should be a pretty common requirement no? Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: try javascript in the page `/login` to redirect to `/authed-page`

Answer (score 2):

You are able to append a URL encoded redirect_to variable to the login URL to get it to redirect after login.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauthed-url
```

That URL will redirect you to /authed-url after login.

Comment: this is correct, except that the redirect_to value should be url encoded to `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauthed-url`

Comment: Good call. I updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this function to check user logging or not.

```
<?php
   if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      echo 'your function for logging user';
   }else{
      echo 'your function for not logging user';
   }
?>
```